# Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc() with std::shared_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers

I'm new to using [C++ smart pointers](https://en.cppreference.com/book/intro/smart_pointers). I wanted to use them in one large project I'm working on, but I'm getting the following error:

```
==21819== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==21819==    at 0x4838E7B: operator delete(void*) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==21819==    by 0x188692: std::_Sp_counted_ptr<std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >*, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::_M_dispose() (shared_ptr_base.h:377)
==21819==    by 0x12F1C9: std::_Sp_counted_base<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::_M_release() (shared_ptr_base.h:155)
==21819==    by 0x12E724: std::__shared_count<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::~__shared_count() (shared_ptr_base.h:706)
==21819==    by 0x1406D9: std::__shared_ptr<std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::~__shared_ptr() (shared_ptr_base.h:1145)
==21819==    by 0x14071B: std::shared_ptr<std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > >::~shared_ptr() (shared_ptr.h:103)
==21819==    by 0x1CAB5A: myProg::LearningSequence::optimize(myProg::ErrorFunction&, std::basic_ofstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >*) (LearningSequence.cpp:60)
==21819==    by 0x12DD6A: main (myScript_1_2.cpp:107)
==21819==  Address 0xb2b90d8 is 24 bytes inside a block of size 48 alloc'd
==21819==    at 0x4837DBF: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==21819==    by 0x1331C8: __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<myProg::RandomSolution, std::allocator<myProg::RandomSolution>, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> >::allocate(unsigned long, void const*) (new_allocator.h:111)
==21819==    by 0x132BA0: std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<myProg::RandomSolution, std::allocator<myProg::RandomSolution>, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> > >::allocate(std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<myProg::RandomSolution, std::allocator<myProg::RandomSolution>, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> >&, unsigned long) (alloc_traits.h:436)
==21819==    by 0x1320E9: std::__allocated_ptr<std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<myProg::RandomSolution, std::allocator<myProg::RandomSolution>, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> > > std::__allocate_guarded<std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<myProg::RandomSolution, std::allocator<myProg::RandomSolution>, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> > >(std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<myProg::RandomSolution, std::allocator<myProg::RandomSolution>, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> >&) (allocated_ptr.h:97)
==21819==    by 0x131988: std::__shared_count<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::__shared_count<myProg::RandomSolution, std::allocator<myProg::RandomSolution>>(std::_Sp_make_shared_tag, myProg::RandomSolution*, std::allocator<myProg::RandomSolution> const&) (shared_ptr_base.h:654)
==21819==    by 0x131206: std::__shared_ptr<myProg::RandomSolution, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::__shared_ptr<std::allocator<myProg::RandomSolution>>(std::_Sp_make_shared_tag, std::allocator<myProg::RandomSolution> const&) (shared_ptr_base.h:1322)
==21819==    by 0x130784: std::shared_ptr<myProg::RandomSolution>::shared_ptr<std::allocator<myProg::RandomSolution>>(std::_Sp_make_shared_tag, std::allocator<myProg::RandomSolution> const&) (shared_ptr.h:360)
==21819==    by 0x12FA99: std::shared_ptr<myProg::RandomSolution> std::allocate_shared<myProg::RandomSolution, std::allocator<myProg::RandomSolution>>(std::allocator<myProg::RandomSolution> const&) (shared_ptr.h:707)
==21819==    by 0x12EE24: std::shared_ptr<myProg::RandomSolution> std::make_shared<myProg::RandomSolution>() (shared_ptr.h:723)
==21819==    by 0x12DB48: main (myScript_1_2.cpp:86)
```

I'm really confused by this, because there is a `std::shared_ptr` created on line 86.

```
86    std::shared_ptr<myProg::LearningMethod> new_learning_method = std::make_shared<myProg::RandomSolution>();
    learning_sequence.add_learning_method( new_learning_method );

    std::shared_ptr<myProg::LearningMethod> new_learning_method2 = std::make_shared<myProg::ParticleSwarm>(myProg::ParticleSwarm(&domain_bounds,
                                                                                                     1.711897,
                                                                                                     1.711897,
                                                                                                     0.711897,
                                                                                                     0.5,
                                                                                                     0.3,
                                                                                                     0.7,
                                                                                                     n_particles_swarm,
                                                                                                     max_n_iters_swarm) );
//        learning_sequence.add_learning_method( new_learning_method2 );

    std::shared_ptr<myProg::LearningMethod> new_learning_method3 = std::make_shared<myProg::LevenbergMarquardt>(l4n::LevenbergMarquardt(max_n_iters_gradient_lm, batch_size, prec_lm ) );
    learning_sequence.add_learning_method( new_learning_method3 );


    /* Complex Optimization */
107    learning_sequence.optimize(mse1);  // Network training
```

The function `optimize()` look like this:

```
   void LearningSequence::optimize(myProg::ErrorFunction &ef, std::ofstream *ofs) {

    double error = ef.eval();

    double the_best_error = error;
    int mcycles = this->max_number_of_cycles, cycle_idx = 0;

    std::shared_ptr<std::vector<double>> best_params = std::make_shared<std::vector<double>>(this->best_parameters);
    while( error > this->tol && mcycles != 0){
        mcycles--;
        cycle_idx++;

        for( auto m: this->learning_sequence ){
            m->optimize( ef, ofs );
            error = ef.eval(m->get_parameters());

            ef.get_network_instance()->copy_parameter_space(m->get_parameters());



            if( error < the_best_error ){
                the_best_error = error;
                this->best_parameters = *ef.get_parameters();
            }

            if( error <= this->tol ){
                ef.get_network_instance()->copy_parameter_space( best_params );
                return;
            }
        }
        COUT_DEBUG("Cycle: " << cycle_idx << ", the lowest error: " << the_best_error << std::endl );
    }
    ef.get_network_instance()->copy_parameter_space( best_params );
}
```

The error further happens in the function `eval()`:

```
double MSE::eval(std::shared_ptr<std::vector<double>> weights,
                 bool denormalize_data,
                 bool verbose) {
    return this->eval_on_data_set(this->ds,
                                  nullptr,
                                  weights,
                                  denormalize_data,
                                  verbose);
    puts("END OF EVAL()");
}
```

which calls `eval_on_data_set()`:

```
   double MSE::eval_on_data_set(myProg::DataSet* data_set,
                                 std::ofstream* results_file_path,
                                 std::shared_ptr<std::vector<double>> weights,
                                 bool denormalize_data,
                                 bool verbose) {
        size_t dim_in = data_set->get_input_dim();
        size_t dim_out = data_set->get_output_dim();
        double error = 0.0, val, output_norm = 0;

        std::vector<std::pair<std::vector<double>, std::vector<double>>>* data = data_set->get_data();
        size_t n_elements = data->size();

        std::vector<std::vector<double>> outputs(data->size());
        std::vector<double> output(dim_out);

        if (verbose) {
            COUT_DEBUG("Evaluation of the error function MSE on the given data-set" << std::endl);
            COUT_DEBUG(R_ALIGN << "[Element index]" << " "
                               << R_ALIGN << "[Input]" << " "
                               << R_ALIGN << "[Real output]" << " "
                               << R_ALIGN << "[Predicted output]" << " "
                               << R_ALIGN << "[Absolute error]" << " "
                               << R_ALIGN << "[Relative error %]"
                               << std::endl);
        }

        if (results_file_path) {
            *results_file_path << R_ALIGN << "[Element index]" << " "
                               << R_ALIGN << "[Input]" << " "
                               << R_ALIGN << "[Real output]" << " "
                               << R_ALIGN << "[Predicted output]" << " "
                               << R_ALIGN << "[Abs. error]" << " "
                               << R_ALIGN << "[Rel. error %]"
                               << std::endl;
        }

        for (auto i = 0; i < data->size(); i++) {  // Iterate through every element in the test set
            /* Compute the net output and store it into 'output' variable */
            this->net->eval_single(data->at(i).first,
                                   output,
                                   weights);

            outputs.at(i) = output;
        }

        double denormalized_output;
        double denormalized_real_input;
        double denormalized_real_output;

        for (auto i = 0; i < data->size(); i++) {

            /* Compute difference for every element of the output vector */
#ifdef DEBUG
            std::stringstream ss_input;
            std::string separator = "";
            for (auto j = 0; j < dim_in; j++) {
                if(denormalize_data) {
                    denormalized_real_input = data_set->get_normalization_strategy()->de_normalize(data->at(i).first.at(j));
                } else {
                    denormalized_real_input = data->at(i).first.at(j);
                }
                ss_input << separator << denormalized_real_input;
                separator = ",";
            }
            if(denormalize_data) {
                denormalized_real_input = data_set->get_normalization_strategy()->de_normalize(data->at(i).first.back());
            } else {
                denormalized_real_input = data->at(i).first.back();
            }

            std::stringstream ss_real_output;
            std::stringstream ss_predicted_output;
#endif

            double loc_error = 0;
            output_norm = 0;
            separator = "";
            for (size_t j = 0; j < dim_out; ++j) {
                if (denormalize_data) {
                    denormalized_real_output = data_set->get_normalization_strategy()->de_normalize(data->at(i).second.at(j));
                    denormalized_output = data_set->get_normalization_strategy()->de_normalize(outputs.at(i).at(j));
                } else {
                    denormalized_real_output = data->at(i).second.at(j);
                    denormalized_output = outputs.at(i).at(j);
                }

#ifdef DEBUG
                ss_real_output << separator << denormalized_real_output;
                ss_predicted_output << separator << denormalized_output;
                separator = ",";
#endif

                val = denormalized_output - denormalized_real_output;
                loc_error += val * val;
                error += loc_error;

                output_norm += denormalized_output * denormalized_output;
            }

#ifdef DEBUG
            std::stringstream ss_ind;
            ss_ind << "[" << i << "]";

            if (verbose) {
                COUT_DEBUG(R_ALIGN << ss_ind.str() << " "
                                   << R_ALIGN << ss_input.str() << " "
                                   << R_ALIGN << ss_real_output.str() << " "
                                   << R_ALIGN << ss_predicted_output.str() << " "
                                   << R_ALIGN << std::sqrt(loc_error) << " "
                                   << R_ALIGN
                                   << 200.0 * std::sqrt(loc_error) / (std::sqrt(loc_error) + std::sqrt(output_norm))
                                   << std::endl);
            }

            if (results_file_path) {
                *results_file_path << R_ALIGN << ss_ind.str() << " "
                                   << R_ALIGN << ss_input.str() << " "
                                   << R_ALIGN << ss_real_output.str() << " "
                                   << R_ALIGN << ss_predicted_output.str() << " "
                                   << R_ALIGN << std::sqrt(loc_error) << " "
                                   << R_ALIGN
                                   << 200.0 * std::sqrt(loc_error) / (std::sqrt(loc_error) + std::sqrt(output_norm))
                                   << std::endl;
            }
#endif
        }

        double result = std::sqrt(error) / n_elements;

        if (verbose) {
            COUT_DEBUG("MSE = " << result << std::endl);
        }

        if (results_file_path) {
            *results_file_path << "MSE = " << result << std::endl;
        }

        puts("END OF EVAL_ON_DATA_SET");
        return result;
    }
```

The strangest thing is, that before the program crashes, *END OF EVAL_ON_DATA_SET* is printed out, but *END OF EVAL()* is not, i.e. the program crashes with the end of the `eval_on_data_set()` function.

Is there any way to find out, what's happening?

Thank you very much for any advice.

---

#### EDIT

I've tried to use Memory Sanitizer according to the xaxxon's advice and here's the output:

```
=================================================================
==6515==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: alloc-dealloc-mismatch (INVALID vs operator delete) on 0x604000001ee8
    #0 0x7f2ad3a55118 in operator delete(void*, unsigned long) (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.5+0xf1118)                                                                              
    #1 0x5589562f445b in std::_Sp_counted_ptr<std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >*, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::_M_dispose() /usr/include/c++/8/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:377
    #2 0x558956239de2 in std::_Sp_counted_base<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::_M_release() /usr/include/c++/8/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:155
    #3 0x5589562386dd in std::__shared_count<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::~__shared_count() /usr/include/c++/8/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:706
    #4 0x5589562383f1 in std::__shared_ptr<std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::~__shared_ptr() /usr/include/c++/8/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:1145
    #5 0x55895623840d in std::shared_ptr<std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > >::~shared_ptr() /usr/include/c++/8/bits/shared_ptr.h:103
    #6 0x558956393484 in myProg::LearningSequence::optimize(myProg::ErrorFunction&, std::basic_ofstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >*) /home/martin/myProg/src/LearningMethods/LearningSequence.cpp:60
    #7 0x55895623685e in main /home/martin/myProg/src/examples/simulator_1_2.cpp:108
    #8 0x7f2ad31cf09a in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x2409a)
    #9 0x558956235669 in _start (/home/martin/myProg/build/bin/examples/simulator_1_2+0x4c669)

0x604000001ee8 is located 24 bytes inside of 48-byte region [0x604000001ed0,0x604000001f00)
allocated by thread T0 here:                                                                                                                                                                 
    #0 0x7f2ad3a53b60 in operator new(unsigned long) (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.5+0xefb60)
    #1 0x558956241b31 in __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<myProg::RandomSolution, std::allocator<myProg::RandomSolution>, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> >::allocate(unsigned long, void const*) (/home/martin/myProg/build/bin/examples/simulator_1_2+0x58b31)
    #2 0x55895624128e in std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<myProg::RandomSolution, std::allocator<myProg::RandomSolution>, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> > >::allocate(std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<myProg::RandomSolution, std::allocator<myProg::RandomSolution>, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> >&, unsigned long) (/home/martin/myProg/build/bin/examples/simulator_1_2+0x5828e)
    #3 0x558956240065 in std::__allocated_ptr<std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<myProg::RandomSolution, std::allocator<myProg::RandomSolution>, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> > > std::__allocate_guarded<std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<myProg::RandomSolution, std::allocator<myProg::RandomSolution>, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> > >(std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<myProg::RandomSolution, std::allocator<myProg::RandomSolution>, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> >&) (/home/martin/myProg/build/bin/examples/simulator_1_2+0x57065)
    #4 0x55895623f2ac in std::__shared_count<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::__shared_count<myProg::RandomSolution, std::allocator<myProg::RandomSolution>>(std::_Sp_make_shared_tag, myProg::RandomSolution*, std::allocator<myProg::RandomSolution> const&) (/home/martin/myProg/build/bin/examples/simulator_1_2+0x562ac)
    #5 0x55895623e4d8 in std::__shared_ptr<myProg::RandomSolution, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::__shared_ptr<std::allocator<myProg::RandomSolution>>(std::_Sp_make_shared_tag, std::allocator<myProg::RandomSolution> const&) (/home/martin/myProg/build/bin/examples/simulator_1_2+0x554d8)
    #6 0x55895623cb90 in std::shared_ptr<myProg::RandomSolution>::shared_ptr<std::allocator<myProg::RandomSolution>>(std::_Sp_make_shared_tag, std::allocator<myProg::RandomSolution> const&) (/home/martin/myProg/build/bin/examples/simulator_1_2+0x53b90)
    #7 0x55895623ade5 in std::shared_ptr<myProg::RandomSolution> std::allocate_shared<myProg::RandomSolution, std::allocator<myProg::RandomSolution>>(std::allocator<myProg::RandomSolution> const&) (/home/martin/myProg/build/bin/examples/simulator_1_2+0x51de5)
    #8 0x5589562394a5 in std::shared_ptr<myProg::RandomSolution> std::make_shared<myProg::RandomSolution>() (/home/martin/myProg/build/bin/examples/simulator_1_2+0x504a5)
    #9 0x558956236538 in main /home/martin/myProg/src/examples/simulator_1_2.cpp:86
    #10 0x7f2ad31cf09a in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x2409a)

SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: alloc-dealloc-mismatch (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.5+0xf1118) in operator delete(void*, unsigned long)
==6515==HINT: if you don't care about these errors you may set ASAN_OPTIONS=alloc_dealloc_mismatch=0
==6515==ABORTING
```

The line 86 with the shared pointer declaration can be seen above and the optimize function too... So, I'm not sure, if I can get some more info this way.

Comment: You really need to show all the lines between where you create the shared_ptr and where your program crashes.  And indicate exactly what happens within any functions that you call.  Chances are that in your conversion process, you may have called `delete` on the shared_ptr's raw pointer.  Or you may have undefined behavior / heap corruption due to a buffer overrun somewhere.  It's very difficult to tell based on the scant information you have provided thus far.

Comment: @paddy Well, I've tried to provide more code - if you need more information, I'll fill it in.

Comment: The error messages smell like a memory corruption error, which is notoriously hard to track down. You need to search for out-of-bounds accesses in a part of the code unrelated to the part that's giving you the errors.

Comment: Is that the very first error reported by valgrind memcheck?

Comment: @aschepler Yes, it is.

Comment: @MarkRansom Do you think, it's possible to find it with some Valgrind flag?

Comment: I highly recommend adding the compiler flag -fsanitize=address and running it again

Comment: @xaxxon Thank you! I've tried it and appended the output into the question.

Comment: @paddy I've added additional info into my question.

Comment: @MarkRansom Could the newly added log from AddressSanitizer help you?

Comment: It seems something is overwriting memory that belongs to `best_params`. My next step would be to run under gdb. Put a breakpoint right after `best_params` is initialized. When you get there, set hardware watchpoints (`watch` command) on `best_params` itself and also on the memory at which it points. `continue`, then each time a hardware watchpoint trigger, look at whether it makes sense for the calling code to be modifying `best_params` or its shared block.